# What is the difference between Boolean(foo.bar) and !!foo.bar?

Tags: javascript, boolean, negation

In `javascript` I have seen the usage of

```
if (!!foo.bar) {
    doSomething();
}
```

What is the performance and other differences between this and

```
if (Boolean(foo.bar)) {
    doSomething();
}
```

?

Is there any overhead for the use of <del>constructor</del> typecasting over negation?

Another (better) example is:

```
doSomethingWithBoolean(!!foo.bar);
```

Comment: If you want to know the performance difference, go to jsperf.com.

Comment: I would just write `if (foo.bar)` instead of either of them.

Comment: @Barmar, I actually changed the example, it fits better in doSomething(!!foo.bar) where doSomething expects a boolean.

Comment: @Close voters: Care to explain?

Comment: I voted to close because you didn't make any attempt to solve the problem yourself before asking. We're not here to run a trivial benchmark for you.

Comment: @barmer: It's asking more than just performance benchmarks. Those things one either knows or doesn't know. I am not aware of how to show 'efforts/attempts' one makes to know. For the record, I have tried running these cases for functions accepting booleans.

Comment: Other than performance, the answers would just be opinions, and opinion-based questions are frowned upon.

Comment: On what basis can one you say that other answers will be just opinions? Maybe post that proof as answer here? And even if they are, I am asking question because I don't know the answer. Is anyone else who stumbles upon the same Q, supposed to know that there are no other differences other than performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `Boolean(foo.bar)` , you are getting a wrapped boolean object which would have some additional Object sspecific functionality (and here you dont want them)

Using `!!foo.bar`  you'll get a boolean literal, So i think this evaluation will be fast.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there will be any significant performance issue. **!!foo.bar** is doing same thing with less typing.

With **boolean(foo.bar)** there might be very-very small performance issue as this is using constructor but with today's hardware that is ignorable.

After all I will simply use **foo.bar** or **!foo.bar**

Answer (score 0):

The double negation is just quicker to type and makes for shortened files. It’s a common compression technique.

It could be (a tiny little bit) slower, but since it’s an ubiquitous shortcut I guess there’s a compiler optimization. Don’t nitpick over such implementation details!

Answer (score -2):

In Javascript, with

```
if (Boolean(foo.bar)) {
    doSomething();
}
```

doSomething will execute since Boolean() create a not null object, even if it is `Boolean(false)`. "Boolean" returns an object, "!!" returns a boolean **value**, e.g. true/false. My source for telling this is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean).

PS: **Boolean**, with a caps at the beginning, is the Javascript object

Comment: What you are saying happens when you do new Boolean()

Comment: @Ricola3D—better fix your answer, it's inconsistent with [EMCA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.6.1.1): `Boolean(value) Returns a Boolean value (not a Boolean object) computed by ToBoolean(value)`.